# What is the preferred way to install spdlib?

Tags: installation, homebrew, conda

I use `homebrew` to install packages on my Mac OS High Sierra. However, I encountered a package called [`spdlib`](http://www.spdlib.org/doku.php) that is not available through `homebrew`. The package is available as an install through `conda` using the following ([source](https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/tag/spdlib/)):

```
conda install -c rios -c conda-forge spdlib
```

What is the preferred method of getting `spdlib` on my machine taking into account I do not want `homebrew` and `conda` to confict?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to install [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html).

Create a new environment:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

activate it:

```
source activate myenv
```

with a new conda this should work too:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Now, you can install what you need without interfering with your homebrew packages:

```
(myenv) conda install -c rios -c conda-forge spdlib
```